# How to union two tables with group values?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to union two tables with group values?

My query:

```
SELECT
   employee.employee_name,
   count(employee.employee_name) as count,
   sum(table1.position)     as totalshares 
FROM
   erom_kmch.table1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   erom.employee 
      ON     employee.bene_type_table1=table1.bene_type     
      AND employee.bene_stype_table1=table1.bene_stype 
WHERE
   table1.date =    '2016-04-15' 
group by
   employee.employee_name 
UNION
SELECT
   employee.employee_name,
   count(employee.employee_name) as count,
   sum(table2.shares) as totalshares    
FROM
   erom_kmch.table2 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   erom.employee     
      ON  employee.type_table2=table2.type     
      AND  employee.bo_substat_table2=table2.bo_substat 
WHERE
   table2.date =   '2016-04-15' 
group by
   employee.employee_name
```

Returns:

```
   employee_name          count    totalshares
    NULL                 0 0       21967
    Clearing Member      9 9       1386
    devloper-php         4 4       1984
    devloper-.net        46 46      410713
    devloper-.android    2
     NULL        4056461       0      117154
     devloper-.C#php        2   5     31618309
     devloper-.net    
     Resident Individual   939  25 361020   22762
```

But I need the output like this:

```
    employee_name         count     totalshares
            NULL             0        139121
      Clearing Member        15       5355
        devloper-php         9        2293
        devloper-.net        46       433475
      devloper-.android      2        4056461
        devloper-.C#         2        31618
       Resident Individual   3668      2662925
      Individual- Director      1        100
```

I am joining and union two tables and I need to group the values of two tables. I am getting two output, I need the sum and count of two tables as one output.

Comment: Put it in a subquery, and sum in the outer query

Comment: By the way, I know mysql allows it, but you should put all attributes which are not in an aggregate function in the `group by`, not the other way around

Comment: show ur original table

Comment: Don't format all text as code...

Comment: haha..he's struggling formatting his question :D

Comment: You sure it returns the output you have shown? there are more fields in the select, than in the output

Answer (score 0):

You should use Subquery:

```
SELECT
      [YourField]
    , [YourAggregate]
FROM
    (SELECT  
          table1.holder
        , table1.bene_type
        , table1.bene_stype
        , employee.employee_name
        , COUNT(employee.employee_name) AS [count]
        , SUM(table1.position) AS totalshares 
    FROM 
        erom_kmch.table1 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        erom.employee 
            ON employee.bene_type_table1=table1.bene_type AND employee.bene_stype_table1=table1.bene_stype 
    WHERE 
        table1.date = '2016-04-15' 
    GROUP BY 
        employee.employee_name 
    UNION 
    SELECT 
      table2.cust_name
      , table2.type
      , table2.bo_substat
      , employee.employee_name
      , COUNT(employee.employee_name) as [count]
      , SUM(table2.shares) as totalshares
    FROM 
        erom_kmch.table2 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        erom.employee 
            ON  employee.type_table2=table2.type AND employee.bo_substat_table2=table2.bo_substat 
    WHERE 
        table2.date = '2016-04-15' 
    GROUP BY employee.employee_name
     ) AS A
GROUP BY
    [YourField]
```

**NOTE:** You should also make the query easy to read.

Comment: By the looks of his output. I don't think it is necessary to select all the columns

Comment: Looks like he/she's having hard time editing & formatting his/her question

Comment: @jonju yep. Can't see which field is [category_name] she/he has in an output

Comment: wait..he/she is still editing I guess. The edit link is disabled